# Subtract value from variant-post before entered in array

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following to extract data from reports and in addition i use formulas to subtract the "VAT" from the "Amount".
My question is if it's possible to avoid using formulas and instead simply subtract the "VAT"-cell value from the "Amount"-cell value before it's entered in the array (line 23 possibly)

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub ExtractData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, MyRange As Range, destination As Range
    Dim pName As Integer, pNr As Integer, amount As Integer, vat As Integer, dDate As Integer, i As Long
    Dim sourceData() As Variant, targetData() As Variant, x As Double


    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    Set MyRange = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set destination = MyRange.Cells(1).Offset(, MyRange.Columns.Count + 1)
    sourceData = MyRange.Value2


    With MyRange
        pName = WorksheetFunction.Match("Product Name", .Rows(1), 0)
        pNr = WorksheetFunction.Match("Product Number", .Rows(1), 0)
        amount = WorksheetFunction.Match("Amount", .Rows(1), 0)
        vat = WorksheetFunction.Match("VAT", .Rows(1), 0)
        dDate = WorksheetFunction.Match("Date", .Rows(1), 0)
    End With

    ReDim targetData(UBound(sourceData, 1), 5)

    For i = 1 To UBound(sourceData, 1)
        targetData(i, 1) = sourceData(i, pName)
        targetData(i, 2) = sourceData(i, pNr)
        targetData(i, 3) = sourceData(i, amount)'-sourceData(i, vat)????
        targetData(i, 4) = sourceData(i, vat)
        targetData(i, 5) = sourceData(i, dDate)
    Next

    destination.Resize(UBound(targetData, 1), UBound(targetData, 2)).Value = targetData

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Please don't use things like "line 23" to refer to a code location. I really don't want to count, having to figure out in the process if blank lines are counted or not.

Comment: What is happening with what you have?

Comment: @Olly as is, it works but if I remove the the comment sign( ' ) I get Runtime Error nr 13.

Comment: @John Coleman Sorry about that, didn't count blank lines and it was only to suggest where it might be possible to edit

Comment: @mrkrister If you paste your code into a VBA editor "line 23" turns out to be `End With`. If you do give line numbers (not really recommended) in VBA it would actually make more sense to include blank lines since then someone would be able to locate it in the VBA editor (when pasted into a blank module). But, instead of line numbers, just say something like "the line that begins ..."

Comment: Runtime error 13 is type mismatch. 

Test the value of "vat" and "sourceData(i, vat)" using debug.print to see whether it's your Match or Value that doesn't return an integer.

Comment: @John Coleman Alright, I will :) line 30 according to the editor  "targetData(i, 3) = sourceData(i, amount)'-sourceData(i, vat)????"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first row tries to subtract two strings. Try this in your For block, the "IF" is the part I changed.

```
For i = 1 To UBound(sourceData, 1)
    targetData(i, 1) = sourceData(i, pName)
    targetData(i, 2) = sourceData(i, pNr)
    If (i <> 1) Then
        targetData(i, 3) = sourceData(i, amount) - sourceData(i, vat)
    Else
        targetData(i, 3) = "Net"
    End If
    targetData(i, 4) = sourceData(i, vat)
    targetData(i, 5) = sourceData(i, dDate)
Next
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! :) It didn't strike me that the headers could be a problem